# possibly an edge/vertex crease error causing crash?

Tags: error

good afternoon! this is the first time i'm asking for error help and i *think* i'm including everything but please let me know if i'm missing something!

i keep getting random crashes, but i think they're mostly happening around crease operations-- i've included the blend file and the error log below, and would really appreciate any help or a nudge in the right direction to solve this error.

thank you!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/avnc0kqmyse0qmg/untitled1.blend?dl=0

https://pastebin.com/edHyu7Nr

Comment: Just found the vertex crease feature today, and I've also found that Blender crashes when you right click to cancel the vertex crease. No problems for edge creases though